# Fading In And Fading Out A Label Infinitively With separate `text`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label

I have a label in xCode that I want to infinitely fade between a word and then the current time.

I've had a look online and can find a single fade but am new to Swift so I'm struggling to adapt this to my need.

Any help would be amazing, Thanks!

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func fade_out(sender: AnyObject) {
    fade(label)
}

@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {
    label.text = "label"
}

func fade(label : UILabel) {
     UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
         label.alpha = 0.0
     }, completion: nil)

     UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
         label.alpha = 1.0
         label.text = String(NSDate())
     }, completion: nil)
}
```

What I do is that I fade out the label first with `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut` and then fade it in again with todays date with `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn`.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TR9xoKqvZNY2Y1WkVObm40bUE/view) is a test project I created for you so that you can see how I have done it.

**Edit**
To do it infinity, you can do it like this and without a button

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var b = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.fade), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func fade() {
        if b{
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.label.alpha = 0.0
                self.label.text = "Label"
                }, completion: nil)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.label.alpha = 1.0
                self.label.text = String(NSDate())
                }, completion: nil)

            b = false
        }
        else{
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.label.alpha = 0.0
                self.label.text = String(NSDate())
                }, completion: nil)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.label.alpha = 1.0
                self.label.text = "Label"
                }, completion: nil)

            b = true
        }

    }
```

Comment: The fade animation and time is what I need, but rather than buttons is there a way to infinitely fade between the two?

Comment: By "infinitely fade between the two" do you mean that you want to fade in and out between them?

Comment: Yes, so it will infinitely fade between the two. Thats the part I've been struggling with. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the original post

Comment: @HarryCollins, added an example of how to do it infinity and without a button press

Comment: @Dravidian, you were right about what he ment and the post is updated now

Answer (score 1):

A much Elegant way will be to use **CAAnimation** ->

```
  class YourClass: UIViewController , ..{

     @IBOutlet weak var fadingLabel: UILabel!
     var a = true


     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()


              NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.swapText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
              let anim : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
              anim.fromValue = 1
              anim.toValue = 0
              anim.duration = 0.5
              anim.autoreverses = true
              anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
              fadingLabel.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "flashOpacity")


     }


     func swapText(){

          if a == true{

              fadingLabel.text = String(NSDate())
              a = false
            }else{

              fadingLabel.text = String("My Text")
              a = true
          }

     }


 }
```

All you gotta do now is manipulate `anim.duration` and timeInterval in NSTimer() accordingly ...

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice way of doing it